# Run multiple tasks with continuation

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I found some strange behavior running tasks within a for loop and awaiting them all. As mentioned below, what the code does is starting a "loop" for definite number of tasks, each task creates a "ToDo" item and each task has a continuation that assigns each created task to a person and finally but them in a listBox using Invoke so the UI thread is called. this works fine, but i do not get the expected data in the listBox. I do not expect them to be ordered, but i do expect them to be paired, e.g. :

Person_8, Todo 8
Person 5, Todo 5
etc...

And they should only appear ones in the listBox of course ! But instead, i get strange output (and output is never the same for each run), here are some examples running the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFvKt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7pwI.png)

And here is the code:

```
private async void buttonCreateToDo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    await CreateToDoAsync();
}

private async Task CreateToDoAsync(){
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        var task = Task.Run(() => CreateToDo(i));
        Task continuation = task.ContinueWith((antecedent) => Invoke(new AssignTaskDelegate(AssignTask), (new Person() {
            Name = $"Person_{i}",
            ToDoForPerson = antecedent.Result
        })));
        taskList.Add(task);

    }
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
}

private ToDo CreateToDo(int toDoId) {
    return new ToDo(){
        Id = toDoId,
        Description = $"Todo {toDoId}"
    };
}

private void AssignTask(Person person){
    listBoxToDo.Items.Add($"{person.Name}, {person.ToDoForPerson.Description}");
}
```

Comment: Continuations are deprecated with `async/await`.   Latter is easier and more readable too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `for` loop runs much faster than the creation of the tasks and so by the time the tasks run the variable `i` has reached the end of the loop.

To fix this you need to take a copy of `i` inside the loop and use that.

Try this code:

```
private async Task CreateToDoAsync()
{
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var local_i = i;
        var task = Task.Run(() => CreateToDo(local_i));
        Task continuation = task.ContinueWith((antecedent) => Invoke(new AssignTaskDelegate(AssignTask), (new Person()
        {
            Name = $"Person_{local_i}",
            ToDoForPerson = antecedent.Result
        })));
        taskList.Add(task);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
}
```

Now, in preference I'd use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive") to do this work. Your code would look like this:

```
private async Task CreateToDoAsync()
{
    var query =
        from i in Observable.Range(1, 9)
        from t in Observable.Start(() => CreateToDo(i))
        select new Person() { Name = $"Person_{i}", ToDoForPerson = t };

    await query.ObserveOn(listBoxToDo).Do(x => AssignTask(x));
}
```

Done. That's it.

When I run my code (with the `AssignTask` outputting to the Console) I get this:

```
Person_1, Todo 1
Person_2, Todo 2
Person_3, Todo 3
Person_6, Todo 6
Person_7, Todo 7
Person_4, Todo 4
Person_5, Todo 5
Person_8, Todo 8
Person_9, Todo 9
```

The `.ObserveOn(listBoxToDo)` works for Windows Forms to marshall back to the UI thread.

Comment: "Your issue is that for loop runs much faster...". Is it really about the speed of `for` loop or is it because of closures?

Comment: @FCin - It's not an "or" it's a both. If the loop waited for each task to complete then the closure wouldn't cause a problem. It's because of both.

Comment: @Enigmativity > of course you're right, the for loop runs much faster then the creation of the tasks, I overlooked this, taking a copy solved the issue ! thanks for your response !

Comment: And  adding a little Thread.Sleep(), which blocks the main (ui) thread for some time after adding each task to the tasklist did the job too, but this isn't a proper solution and only proves that the for loop runs much faster.

Answer (score -2):

You are using variable "i" from the loop inside the task. "i" might have changed while your task started.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit clearer here on what the actual problem is.

Comment: What's not clear enough? Variable i from outside the task is used inside the task, thus changing while the task is running. Can you elaborate on what is not clear about it?

Comment: Just speaking from my personal experience on this site. Up to you if you want to stick with what you've got.

Comment: Hi Markus, yes that's what i thought too ! Then i changed the code using a shared id (instead of the "i" variable of the loop), and locked the shared id in the CreateTodo() method, so a single task get only get exclusive access at a time, so code shanged to:

Comment: private ToDo CreateToDo()
        {
            lock(_threadLock)
            {
                _sharedId++;
            }
            return new ToDo()
                {
                    Id = _sharedId,
                    Description = $"Todo {_sharedId}"
                };
            

        }

Comment: @EmmanuelNuyttens - There's no need to no any locking so long as you copy the variable inside your loop.

Comment: @EmmanuelNuyttens - If you're doing incrementing the `_sharedId` in your loop you'll end up with the same problem.